# MySQL Data returned in Different Orders

Tags: mysql

i have MYSQL Table like

```
sender| recepient      |message
type01| 923007957585   |same msg
type01| 923018976543   |same msg
type01| 923037865456   |same msg
type02| 923456812536   |type 2 msg
type03| 923111111111   |type 3 msg
```

Want to get Result as

recepient=923007957585,923018976543,923037865456&same msg

recepient=923456812536&type 2 msg

recepient=923111111111&type 3 msg

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: Your expected result is very unclear. Please be specific about exactly what format you want, which values in which column or if that is a PHP data type, what type and arranged how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(recipient) as recipients, message
from table t
group by message;
```

Comment: after fetching data how to distinguish Result ??

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I CAN understand what you trying to say, you need to find out single sender  to multiple receiver..i.e one to many relation...
Possibly you can use GROUP BY  sender and having 
clause together.

GOrdan is right.
// use group by sender

```
select group_concat(recipient) as recipients, message
from table t
group by sender;
```

Comment: logan is right .
the problem is to distingush them .
How to get result using fetch array ??